# Using two readers one nested inside the other

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, nested

Currently i am trying to dynamically generate some buttons for a music player i am developing and i am currently trying to retrieve album art from the tags of the music so that it can be added as a background image for the button. My current method of doing this is having two readers one which selects all the information about the album and one that fetches a directory location of a song in the album from the database of songs so that i can use taglib to fetch the album art information and convert it to a System.Drawing.Image. However to do this i am using a reader nested inside a reader and i can't seem to get the nested reader's connection working. Currently I'm using two connections one for each reader/command one called connection and one called connection2 both with the same connection string:

```
server=localhost; port=3306; userid=KEVIN; password=; database=kevin;
```

However when i run the code below i get this error:[image]

```
public void createAlbumButtons(int x, FlowLayoutPanel field)
    {
        MySqlCommand selectAlbumsTable = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Albums ORDER BY Artist ASC, Album DESC", connect);
        MySqlDataReader readAlbumsTable = selectAlbumsTable.ExecuteReader();
        while (readAlbumsTable.Read())
        {
            MySqlCommand selectAlbumIDFromFirstSong = new MySqlCommand("SELECT SongLocation FROM Music Where AlbumID= \"" + readAlbumsTable.GetString(0) + "\" LIMIT 1", connect2);
            MySqlDataReader readAlbumIDFromFirstSong = selectAlbumIDFromFirstSong.ExecuteReader();
            while (readAlbumIDFromFirstSong.Read())
            {
                string temp = readAlbumIDFromFirstSong.GetString(0).Replace("\\\"", "\\");
                TagLib.File findAlbumArt = TagLib.File.Create(temp);
                MemoryStream memstrm;
                try
                {
                    memstrm = new MemoryStream(findAlbumArt.Tag.Pictures[0].Data.Data);
                    albumCoverImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(memstrm);
                }
                catch
                {
                    albumCoverImage = KEVIN.Properties.Resources.NoAlbumArt;

                }
                field.Controls.Add(AttachMethodToButton(new Button
                {
                    Name = "Album" + readAlbumsTable.GetString(0),
                    ForeColor = Color.WhiteSmoke,
                    Text = readAlbumsTable.GetString(1) + "\n" + readAlbumsTable.GetString(2),
                    TextAlign = ContentAlignment.BottomCenter,
                    Size = new Size(130, 130),
                    BackgroundImage = albumCoverImage,
                    BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Zoom,
                    FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat,
                    FlatAppearance =
                    {
                        BorderSize = 1,
                        BorderColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#444444"),
                    },
                }, () => openAlbumForm()));
                x++;
            }
        }

    }
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Many Thanks

- Ross

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not obvious where connect and connect2 are assigned, but based on the exception it doesnt sound like connect2 is an open connection.

You should be able to reuse the first connect object I think which would be more sensible.

```
MySqlCommand selectAlbumIDFromFirstSong = new MySqlCommand("SELECT SongLocation FROM Music Where AlbumID= \"" + readAlbumsTable.GetString(0) + "\" LIMIT 1", connect);
```

As mentioned in other comments another sensible strategy would be to make a single call and do the join in SQL since it is good at that and db calls are relatively expensive (you are making one for every iteration of the outer loop in your implementation).

Keeping them separate makes the SQL more reusable so it really depends on your requirements and how much data youre dealing with.

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess that your second command is unable to open a database connection because the first command is still using it; to be honest I think you're trying to solve the wrong problem here.  You should combine your two queries into a single statement; there's no need to use nested queries in the example you've posted.  Instead of

```
SELECT * FROM Albums ORDER BY Artist ASC, Album DESC
SELECT SongLocation FROM Music Where AlbumID = @albumId
```

try this:

```
SELECT     m.SongLocation
FROM       Music m
INNER JOIN Albums a ON m.AlbumId = a.AlbumId
ORDER BY   a.Artist ASC, a.Album DESC
```

You'll probably also want to look into using a GROUP BY clause (e.g. `GROUP BY a.AlbumId`) as you won't want to output one row for each song in the album; grouping by either album or artist would make most sense, of course...

Comment: this is comment .

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
using (StreamReader outFile = new StreamReader(outputFile.OpenRead()))
using (StreamReader expFile = new StreamReader(expectedFile.OpenRead())) 
{
    ///...
}
```